# Looking for a way to extract internalTransactions in a Ethereum Transaction

Tags: java, ethereum, blockchain, go-ethereum

I am using an Ethereum full node (geth) to retrieve blocks and transaction data, and my Java + Spring Boot project utilizes Web3j to read this data from the full node and store it in my database. Currently, I am capturing the 'value' field, which indicates the amount of ETH transferred in a transaction. However, some Ethereum transactions do not involve the transfer of ETH; instead, they interact with smart contracts or perform other operations. To accurately calculate the value of these internal transactions, I believe I need to use a method called debug_tracetransaction().

The issue is that I couldn't find this specific method within the Web3j library. Can anyone guide me on how to retrieve the value of internal transactions or suggest an alternative approach to achieve this?

Tried to curl debug_tracetransaction() from my full node but got no response.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.